# How to set text of a view defined in the Main Activity (no XML)

Tags: java, android, button, layout

I have a textView that is first created in the Main Activity onCreate file. Like this

```
Button btn = new Button();
```

And then I set some attributes of it like an Id and some LayoutParams

```
btn.setText("Button");
btw.setId("btn");
btn.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

So my question is how can I access this Id within the same file to change the text of the button. Like

```
findViewById(R.id.btn);
```

Except when I do this I get an error. I am assuming since this is not defined within the XML.

EDIT: I cannot pre define these buttons in xml as they are generated based on other factors of the program.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need its id? Define your `Button` as global variable inside `MainActivity`, and use it anywhere you want inside that file.

Comment: @Yildirim Yes but I need ids so based on input I can update the buttons accordingly.

Comment: `findViewById` is generally used for inflating UI elements you define in activity's corresponding XML file, not for UI elements that you create in Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findViewById()` gets an integer, so in order to get a reference to your dynamically created `TextView`, it's enough to pass the same ID to this method.

```
// Assign it ID 100, for example, when you're creating it
btw.setId(100);
```

In this example you can find it using:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(100);
```

Note that `findViewById` only finds views attached to the hierarchy, so you should make sure you have attached your dynamically created `TextView` to the hierarchy.

---

**Alternate way:** Saving the reference as a class member.

First define a private class member of your `MainActivity` class. And then initialize it in your `onCreate` method. So, wherever you need this `TextView` within the activity class, it's enough to use that class member.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    // This is the class member, I was talking about
    private TextView mTextView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         mTextView = new TextView(this);
         mTextView.setText("Button");

         mTextView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
             ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }


    public void someMethod(){
        // Here you can reach to that TextView by using its reference saved in mTextView
       mTextView.setText("Hi there!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I have done that. Is there any way of doing this without findViewById? So you could bypass the integration Id assignment?

Comment: @Fidel_Willis You can simply save the reference as a class member.

Comment: @Fidel_Willis Alternatively you can do `setTag` and `findViewWithTag`.

Comment: Sorry I am just starting to learn Android development could you elaborate on that or provide an example. It would be greatly appreciated thanks

Comment: @Fidel_Willis Yeah, I'm here to help you! _"could you elaborate on that or provide an example."_ example of which method? class member or setting tag?

Comment: Okay thank you for clearing that up, and for your time!